# Wordpress REST API - get custom taxonomy category posts

Tags: custom-taxonomy, rest-api, api, wp-api

I want to use Wordpress REST API to get the posts that are inside a custom taxonomy created by the theme.

The taxonomy is called "my_portfolio" but if I use this I have this response:

> {"code":"rest_no_route","message":"Nessun percorso fornisce una
> corrispondenza tra l'URL ed il metodo
> richiesto.","data":{"status":404}}

Instead if I use "my_portfolio_category" I have 4 categories that are called: "photo", "video", "design", "web".

I want to retrieve the posts inside the category "photos" but the only thing I managed to get is the category info.

The API I used is the one down below where 921 is the ID of the category "photo", using the slug doesn't work.

https://www.mywebsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/my_portfolio_category/921

Is there a way to get the posts?

Answer (score 1):

You need to first register rest route for your custom taxonomy i.e. my_portfolio

```
add_filter( 'register_taxonomy_args', 'my_portfolio_taxonomy', 10, 2 );
 
function my_portfolio_taxonomy( $args, $taxonomy_name ) {
 
    if ( 'my_portfolio' === $taxonomy_name ) {
        $args['show_in_rest'] = true;
 
        // Optionally customize the rest_base or rest_controller_class
        $args['rest_base']             = 'my-portfolio';
        $args['rest_controller_class'] = 'WP_REST_Terms_Controller';
    }
 
    return $args;
}
```

After that you can access url like : http://yourdomain.in/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?my-portfolio=28

Please note 28 is custom taxonomy id. you need to add id of photos in that case

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `'show_in_rest' => true` as an argument when you register your taxonomy with register_taxonomy. Then you'll get a route by WordPress. No need to create your own route.

The route will be: `.../wp/v2/my_portfolio`